# Classification of Compact Symplectic Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $M=G/H$ be a compact homogeneous space, $G$ a compact Lie Group and $H$ a closed subgroup.  Is there some classification, akin to the Kaehler case, for which such manifolds admit a symplectic structure?

I am aware of partial classifications when $G$ has additional properties, but unaware of which cases are completely classified and which are still open.

Comment: You don't require the symplectic form to be $G$-invariant, do you?

Comment: In general, no, it does not have to be G-invariant. However, most constructions of a symplectic form on $M$ will automatically produce such an object.

Comment: If a Lie group $G$ acts transitively on a symplectic manifold $M$, then $M$ is a cover of a coadjoint orbit of a central extension of $M$. If $G$ is compact connected, then its central extensions are trivial enough and its coadjoint orbits are simply connected, so $M$ is just a coadjoint orbit of $G$, hence Kähler. Which is to say, there are no new examples if the symplectic form is $G$-invariant.

Comment: If you don't require $G$-invariance, maybe you can also figure out whether $G_2/SU(3)$ admits a complex structure...